# User registration activation, active boolean and token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, activation

I want to add an emailed activation link for the user who create an account on my app. But I don't know how to adapt my database more efficiently. I have two ideas :

Either I add an `active` boolean and an `active_token` string. When the user is created, the `active` boolean is false, and the `active_token` is generated. Then the user clicks on the activation link he received by mail, and the `active` boolean becomes true and the `active_token` whatever. But if I do that, my database will be full of nil `active_token`, as soon as the user's accounts are activated.

Or I add a `inactive` string. When the user is created, the `inactive` string contains a random generated token, and when the user activate his account, the `inactive` string is set to nil. So I could create a method like :

```rb
def self.active
  !self.inactive
end
```

Do you have a best way to do that ? If not, which would be better in these two ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it like this. Put these two fields in DB

```
activated_on (DATETIME) & activation_token (CHAR)
```

By this you can estimate if the user is active and when he/she became active.

Comment: But the `activation_token` will be nil as soon as the user will be activated. So I will have a full column of nil, when the database will be populated ?